# AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'members'

Tags: python, discord

I'm trying to build a bot that changes the name of a channel when someone joins. Here's my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(guild):
    await update_channel(guild)
    new_name = f"{member_count(guild)}"
    await channelid.edit(name=new_name)


channelid = *redacted*
def update_channel(guild):
    return len(guild.members)
```

However, I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'members'

What's the reason for this error, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Discord API, but judging from the error, the `guild` object you're passing around is of type `Member`, and a `Member` does not have a `members` property. Your code indicates you think the object is of some other type.

Comment: You should import Guild module instead of Member module, as mentioned in this documentation, members is an attribute from class `discord.Guild` https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#guild

Comment: That solved it, thank you @abdou_dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have imported the wrong module, You should import the `Guild` module instead of the `Member` module, as mentioned in this documentation, members is an attribute from class `discord.Guild`

See this for more details:

[Discord API Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#guild)